# Perzonalizar change_list del panel administrativo en Django

Tags: template, django-admin

Llevo semanas leyendo y probando alternativas para lograr personalizar el Change_List (Dentro del panel de administración de Django, donde se muestra el listado de componentes de nuestra aplicación permitiendo adicionar, modificar o eliminar).

Sucede que muestra una tabla con varios registros, junto a un campo de filtrado y otras opciones.

Toso esto se genera automáticamente usando los formularios genéricos de DJango. Lo que necesito es adaptarlo para usar Boostrap y Metronic, pero sin tener que volver a programar todo yo. Hacer la misma plantilla genérica solo incluyéndole las etiquetas CSS y opciones para embellecerlo un poco.

Alguien tiene idea de como hacer eso?

Saludos y gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo a mi mismo...

Solo basta editar el template change_list_result.html para modificar la tabla. 
En el caso del campo de búsqueda solo es preciso modificar el search_form.html

Saludos